# How to produce the file status " R" in git?

Tags: git

For a git tool I want an understanding of the file status " R".  How can I produce this file status for testing?

Typically you do

```
$ git mv README.md roadme.md
$ git status --porcelain
R  README.md -> roadme.md
```

That's "R " not " R".  And when I unstage this:

```
$ git restore --staged roadme.md
$ git status --porcelain
D  README.md
?? roadme.md
```

which is what anyone sees typically and often.

Now, I had " R" once and my tool misbehaved over it.  I had to move on though and now I cannot reproduce it for further investigation and essentially a deeper knowledge.

There is also " C" but I've never seen this.  Maybe you also know how to reproduce this file status.

Comment: The format in general is explained here: https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-status#_short_format. Is this what you are asking or are you asking specifically how you can get a "rename" status in the working tree but not in the index?

Comment: I want a reproduction.  Do this and and that and finally you have the porcelain " R".  That should probably gain some insight as well as I obviously can't do it (reproduce it)  right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to reach that:

```
mv README.md roadme.md
git add --intent-to-add roadme.md
```

`README.md` should not be marked as "to be deleted" in the index, run `git reset README.md` to unstage that deletion if it was there.

Comment: That's bloody genius.  I certainly need a better understanding of what "intent-to-add" actually means and does.  I don't even know where that information is stored.  Can you think of a more natural way to get this result as I saw this in the wild but never did "intent-to-add".  The shortness is of course perfect for the testcase I need to write.

Comment: @herr.kaste: no, this is as "natural" as it gets. If I understand correctly, `--intent-to-add` "adds" a blob in the index, at the path you expect (e.g: `roadme.md` or `path/to/file.txt`), with the bogus sha `00000....` as its content, and `git status` processes that information (the presence of a f`0000...` blob) in a special way.

Comment: @herr.kaste re *"a more natural way to get this result"* - FWIW, the [docs](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-status#_short_format) talk about a merge or merge conflict, so maybe that's how, but I can't think of how that would work off the top of my head.

Comment: "       `-N`, `--intent-to-add`  
           Record only the fact that the path will be added later. An entry for the path is placed  
           in the index with no content. This is useful for, among other things, showing the  
           unstaged content of such files with `git diff` and committing them with `git commit -a`."

Answer (score 2):

@LeGEC has the correct answer:

```
mv README.md roadme.md
git add --intent-to-add roadme.md
```

is the shortest path for e.g. a testcase to produce a " R" status.  How does that work, though?

```
$ mv README.md roadme.md
$ git st --porcelain
 D README.md
?? roadme.md
```

This is the typical output: the oldfile isn't there anymore and gets a " D" and then git sees a new
file which gets a "??".  Now, `--intent-to-add` transforms the "??" to an " A" by putting an empty
entry "roadme.md" in the index.  (It stages an empty version of the file.)

So we have

```
 D README.md
 A roadme.md
```

and git can see how this change has come to happen, namely by renaming.  (The actual content of the
files did not change.)  So it simplifies this `(" D", " A")` pair, and produces

```
$ git add --intent-to-add roadme.md
$ git st --porcelain
 R README.md -> roadme.md
```